# Messi simple jQuery message box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popup

I have download the messi all files like `.js` and `.css` also i have download the jQuery framework and now i have put these codes in my HTML page:

```
<html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="messi.min.css" />
      <script src="messi.js"></script>
    </head>
    <title>messi box</title>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

The messi support told me how to setup. Check below:

Setup

Messi requires jQuery framework to work, so include it first of all in
 your project. After that:

Download Messi from gitHub and descompress. Copy messi.css and
 messi.js files (or minified version) to your project folder.

Edit you html pages to include both files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="messi.min.css" />
<script src="messi.js"></script>
```

Enjoy it! you can find this tutorial at [HERE](http://marcosesperon.es/apps/messi/) I just want to know
 how can I use this in my html page. For example I want to use warning
 message box

```
New Messi('This is a message with `Messi.', {title: 'Title', titleClass: 'anim error', buttons: [{id: 0, label: 'Close', val: 'X'}]});`
```

Is it java code or whatever else? I need complete guide about this plugin.
Thanks

[Plugin can find here](http://marcosesperon.es/apps/messi/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to include JQuery in a similar fashion as `messi.js`. Include JQuery **before** messi.js. Something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery2.1.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="messi.min.css" />
<script src="messi.js"></script>
```

Please note that JQuery 2.x does not support IE 6, 7 or 8 and if you need this support, then consider JQuery 1.x.

The code you have posted is [Javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript).

Comment: `new Messi('This is a message with Messi.', {title: 'Title', titleClass: 'anim error', buttons: [{id: 0, label: 'Close', val: 'X'}]});` how to use this code in html code for showing popup i mean i need to put this code under javascript tag or other ?

Comment: i want that when page load this pop up message appear immediately.

Comment: Giovanni Le Grand has answered already. I suggest you start from the very basics of HTML and Javascript: how those differ and how to get Javascript executed. The internet has an abundance of sources, e.g. http://www.htmldog.com/guides/javascript/beginner/makingstuffhappen/

Answer (score 0):

well it depends on how to use the code,
if you want it to act when the page is loaded you can use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ new Messi('This is a message with Messi.', {title: 'Title', titleClass: 'anim error', buttons: [{id: 0, label: 'Close', val: 'X'}]}); });
```

or if you want it to act when clicked on something you can use it like:

```
$('a#messi').click(function(){ new Messi('This is a message with Messi.', {title: 'Title', titleClass: 'anim error', buttons: [{id: 0, label: 'Close', val: 'X'}]}); });
```

just replace the a#messi with the tag and/or the class/id

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
new Messi('This is a message with Messi.', {title: 'Title', titleClass: 'anim error', buttons: [{id: 0, label: 'Close', val: 'X'}]});
</script>` i have put this code in my page under body tag but still did not work

Comment: yeah i noticed i made a tiny mistake and edited the code part you have to add the new messi part inside the $(document).ready(function(){ PLACE THE MESSI PART HERE });

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
new $(document).ready(function(){ PLACE THE MESSI PART HERE });
</script>` i have put this but still did not work

Comment: in my reaction there i have the proper set up piece of javascript code copy that and paste it, to explain how it works: you want to do something when the page is loaded so for that we have the part: $(document).ready(); we want something to happen so we have to post something inside the ready, in this case create a messi popup so we place the whole new messi part inside: $(document).ready(function(){ new Messi('This is a message with Messi.', {title: 'Title', titleClass: 'anim error', buttons: [{id: 0, label: 'Close', val: 'X'}]}); });

Answer (score 0):

as heikkim said start with learning the basics of HTML5 and Javascript, you can find out alot on several sites, i recommend: http://w3schools.com if you want to find out about the function and tags or go to codecademy.com (or something like this) where you can actually learn the beginnings of html and javascript.